# R how to add border countries to a country spatialpolygons map

Tags: r, maps

I am trying to make some colerful maps using spatialpolygons with R. I downloaded the shapefile from gadm.org website and colored the regions as I wanted following http://bl.ocks.org/prabhasp/raw/5030005/ . However, I think the map would look much better if I were able to put on the map also  part of the countries Vietnam shares the border with, as in this wikipedia map

[image: vietnam_wiki]

I have no clue what to start with, could someone give me a hint? Should I dowload the regional map and then join the regions for the border countries and work at the provincial level for Vietnam? Or can I plot my Vietnam map over the country level one?

Comment: If you are using ggplot as in the linked bl.ocks code, you can easily add more polygons as long as you have the shape data. It's just a matter of adding more rows to the source dataframe

Comment: by source dataframe you mean the dataframe created by the command fortify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a one-off, I'd be inclined to do it this way.

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
vietnam  <- getData("GADM",country="Vietnam",level=2)
china    <- getData("GADM",country="China",level=0)
laos     <- getData("GADM",country="Laos",level=0)
cambodia <- getData("GADM",country="Cambodia",level=0)
thailand <- getData("GADM",country="Thailand",level=0)

ggplot(vietnam,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=id),color="grey30")+
  geom_polygon(data=china,fill="grey60",color="grey80")+
  geom_polygon(data=laos,fill="grey60",color="grey80")+
  geom_polygon(data=cambodia,fill="grey60",color="grey80")+
  geom_polygon(data=thailand,fill="grey60",color="grey80")+
  coord_map(xlim=c(-1,1)+bbox(vietnam)["x",],ylim=c(-1,1)+bbox(vietnam)["y",])+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide="none")+
  theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

Labelling the border countries is trickier because you have to know where to put the labels, and you can't use the country centroids because they are off the map. I'd be includes to eyeball it, and use `annotate(geom="text",...)`.

Comment: Mhh, this does the trick but I am having trouble adapting all the code that goes with it to color the provinces. I mean, the code in the ggplot command is somewhat different from what I used so far (exactly like in the link). I will have a look at the manual first to see what is the difference between geop_map and geom_polygon. Thanks